# How to define button colors for dark mode in theme-ui theme config

Tags: javascript, theme-ui

I'm using theme-ui library to make my ui lib, however, I have a question. Is it possible to specify button colors for dark mode in theme?
for example, do something like this?

```
...
primary: {
    color: 'white',
    bg: 'black',
    variants: {
      dark: {
        bg: 'white',
        color: 'black',
      },
    },
  },
...
```

if I do like this and use button in jsx then it is not affects (

```
<Button variant="primary">click me</Button>
```

I made a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-colden-9xpyz8?file=/src/theme.js) to demonstrate this problem. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found answer on my question after raised [this issue](https://github.com/system-ui/theme-ui/issues/2407).
So my config was ok, the thing is `Theme UI doesn't switch styles per color mode, just colors.` So when I use on button styles colors like 'main', 'secondary' it will changed with theme switch. otherwise no.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to specify button colors for dark mode in the theme using the Theme UI library. In fact, the code snippet you have provided is a valid way to define a button color in the theme for both light and dark modes.

The variants property allows you to define variants for a specific theme object. In this case, you are defining a primary button with a white color and black background for light mode. Then, you are defining a dark variant for the primary button that has a black color and white background for dark mode.

To use this theme object in your UI components, you can use the sx prop provided by Theme UI. For example, to create a button using this theme object, you can do the following:

```
import { Button } from 'theme-ui';

const MyButton = () => (
  <Button
    sx={{
      variant: 'primary',
    }}
  >
    Click me!
  </Button>
);
```

Comment: hmmm... don't know why but it doesn't work (.
I set color mode to dark and button do not reflect

Comment: Variant dark perhaps?

Comment: no. I do not understand why it is not applied. I made a code sandbox for this example. frustraiting

Comment: @DanMullin can you show me in the codesandbox I shared?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fully qualify the path to the variant:

```
variant: "buttons.primary.variants.dark"
```

Comment: I don't get it. Where should I point this path? In variant assignation at template?